# error_reporting showing unwanted NOTICE logs

Tags: php, log-files, pecl, pear

I am getting following notices in php errorlog file.

```
[10-Mar-2011 13:58:39] PHP Notice:  require_once() [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: 1. h-&gt;opened_path=[/home/www/XXXXX/Core/QAjax.php]  h-&gt;filename=[/home/www/XXXXX/include/project/Core/QAjax.php]
 in /home/www/XXXXX/modules/quantum_bootstrap.php on line 54
[10-Mar-2011 13:58:39] PHP Notice:  require_once() [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: 1. h-&gt;opened_path=[/home/www/XXXXX/Core/Memcache.php]  h-&gt;filename=[/home/www/XXXXX/Core/Memcache.php]
 in /home/www/XXXXX/include/project/Core/QAjax.php on line 22
[10-Mar-2011 13:58:41] PHP Notice:  require_once() [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: 1. h-&gt;opened_path=[/home/www/XXXXX/cache/Parameters.php]  h-&gt;filename=[/home/www/XXXXX/include/cache/Parameters.php]
 in /home/www/XXXXX/include/modules/quantum_bootstrap.php on line 15
[10-Mar-2011 13:58:41] PHP Notice:  require_once() [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: 1. h-&gt;opened_path=[/home/www/XXXXX/include/modules/headers.php]  h-&gt;filename=[/home/www/XXXXX/include/modules/headers.php]
 in /home/www/XXXXX/include/modules/quantum_bootstrap.php on line 17
```

However, I turned off notices in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

When I switch it only to E_ERROR it is also in the log.

I am using php-cgi and folowing extensions:

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package   Version State
APC       3.1.7   beta
gearman   0.7.0   beta
memcache  2.2.6   stable
memcached 1.0.2   stable

Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version  State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7    stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1    stable
Log              1.12.5   stable
PEAR             1.9.2    stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4    stable
System_Daemon    1.0.0RC1 beta
XML_Util         1.2.1    stable
```

Comment: Which php version do you use? And how looks one of these lines where the error happen?

Comment: PHP 5.3.5 (cgi-fcgi)

`22:        require_once(CPARAM_APPLICATION_ROOT.'include/project/Core/Memcache.php');

54:            require_once(CPARAM_APPLICATION_ROOT.'include/project/Core/QAjax.php');


15:require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../include/cache/Parameters.php';

17:    require_once (CPARAM_APPLICATION_ROOT.'/include/modules/headers.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ourself. There was a redefining directive in php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However I still don't know why it's classify as "PHP Notice".

Comment: There is bug in APC 3.1.7 always setting APC in debug mode (even if we choose no).